# A book that describes 7 layers of existence, we are living in the 3rd one and we know heaven as the 5th

Tags: story-identification, books

As a child I read a book that describes 7 layers of existence, 'we' are living in the 3rd one and we know heaven as the 5th. The book describes a journey, I believe by a boy and his sister and possible some more, of them travelling from the 3rd through the 4th to the 5th world.

I don't know much about it anymore, it's easily been 20 years. I seem to remember it discussed a nazi concentration camp as well. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Update: I'm also quite sure either the 1st or 2nd layers were the ones for stones and other inanimate objects. If it was the first, the 2nd may have been plantlife but that's just a guess.

Comment: 7 Layers of Existence sounds like the Night Watch series by  Sergei Lukyanenko, but alas the other details don't fit.

Comment: Also sounds like Clive Barker's Imagica but several details aren't right and I don't think you would have read that as a child...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I checked them both out (and Imajica has been on my to-read list for quite some time) but neither seem to be the book I remember.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're referring to [Dante's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante%27s_Equation), a Philip K. Dick Award nominated novel by Jane Jensen, the game designer of the [Gabriel Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Knight) game series. It blends ideas from kabbalah and quantum physics to explain travel between "dimensions", and its plot contains scenes in the Auschwitz concentration camp.
Only problem is that the novel was written in 2003, which makes it unlikely that you read it 20 years ago, unless you're a time traveller.

Comment: It's not quite the same (and it couldn't have been, I'm sure it wasn't just 10 years ago), but interesting that it also describes a concentration camp.